# Copying values from a specified cell in Sheet1 into a specified range of the selected sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to paste values from a range of cells in sheet1 into a specific range set in previously selected/activated sheets. Thus I want it to paste in let say only range B1 onwards but only for the sheets Sheet2, Sheet3 and NOT for Sheet4 since I have not selected it on my workbook.

```
Sub CopyFirstRow()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim mySelectedSheets As Sheets

Wb.Sheets("Global").Range("B1", "Q39").Copy

Set mySelectedSheets = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets


For Each Sht In mySelectedSheets
            ActiveSheet.Paste
Sht.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
End With

End Sub
```

Please explain what I am doing wrong, as I am trying to understand more and more VBA and specifically the SET, FOR, WITH functions.

Answer (score 0):

You dim'd the wb but never set the workbook.

You have two "End With"'s but have no starting  "With"'s
.

You have Activesheet.paste but have not selected a sheet

```
Sub Button1_Click()


    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim mySelectedSheets As Sheets

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

    Wb.Sheets("Global").Range("B1", "Q39").Copy

    Set mySelectedSheets = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets


    For Each Sht In mySelectedSheets
        Sht.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```